# Different in theme as table and page

Tags: theming

I am studying the pager_example in example module. 

When creating an render array, it first assign #theme as 'table'. But it assign the #theme as 'pager' just before returning.
What is the purpose of attach the pager theme ?
pager_example.module:

```
// Create a render array ($build) which will be themed as a table with a
// pager.
$build['pager_table'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => $rows,
  '#empty' => t('There are no date formats found in the db'),
);

// attach the pager theme
$build['pager_pager'] = array('#theme' => 'pager');  <---- why need this ?
return $build[];
```

Then I remove the coding "$build['pager_pager'] = array('#theme' => 'pager');". The result is the same. 
When compare to tablesort_example.module, it don't have attach the pager theme before the return.
tablesort_example.module:

```
// build the table for the nice output.
$build['tablesort_table'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => $rows,
);

return $build;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code `$build['pager_pager'] = array('#theme' => 'pager');` returns the pager for the table.

The example module output with that line of code:

[image]

The example module output without that line of code:

[image]

If you are not seeing the same difference I am, it might be a cache issue, try clearing your cache between changes.

Comment: Thx Scott. You are awesome. I find the different after clearing the cache.